# Adjective request for fast, lightweightness and multitasking

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I am deciding some product name which has characteristics like Fast and lightweight and multitasking.

Please suggest some name which includes these meaning or bird or animal which has such qualities.

Comment: "Agile" is a word that connotes at least two of the 3 qualities you mention. As for animals, the cat family embodies speed and ligh-weight. So you can use panther, puma or cheetah in your name. Just be careful not to copy an already existing brand name (Puma is an existing brand name).

Comment: How about 'fly-by-light'? WEAR FLY-BY-LIGHT FOOTWEAR!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about product naming.

Comment: (Please note that naming is off-topic here because good names are largely a matter of opinion. Also, names have some idiosyncratic rules that make naming questions less generally helpful to other people.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the commonly used words for describing someone who is fast, lightweight and multitasker:

**Ninja**

**Superman**

**Superhuman**

**Ubermansch**

**Hero**

Answer (score 1):

The [hummingbird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hummingbird) is swift, multitasking, and particularly lightweight.